# Sqlite ordering method

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to do some kind of an ordering method for the items I have in a `sqlite` database. At first I have this `RecyclerView` that loads data from the database.
[image: Rows]

Via the drag handle I drag the rows to the desired position. The thing I want to do is save that position and to be able to get it and rearrange the rows exactly the same next time I start the app.

I tried detecting when a row is moved via the `onItemMove` method of the `RecyclerView.Adapter` class and saving the new positions for the rows that swapped positions but the positions get messed up and I don't get the desired result. Maybe the solution is fine but my ordering method is messed up.. This is what I implemented before passing the data to the adapter

```
public static ArrayList<Package> orderPackages(ArrayList<Package> packages) {
        for(int i = 0; i < packages.size(); i++) {
            Package p = packages.get(i);
            int desiredPosition = p.getPosition();
            if(desiredPosition != -1) {
                if(desiredPosition < packages.size()) {
                    Package tempPackage = packages.get(i);
                    packages.remove(i);
                    packages.add(tempPackage.getPosition(), tempPackage);
                }
            }
        }
        return packages;
    }
```

So is there any better solution to remember the position where a row was moved so the next time I start the app the row will be placed in that same location in the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar list as you do and the way I accomplish remembering the position is to implement a listener that passes the whole Arraylist back from the Adapter to the Activity or Fragment like this.

First here is the Listener

```
public interface OnFieldListChangeListener {
    void onDefaultListChanged(List<String> fields);
}
```

Then in the adapter I set that listener like this

```
 private OnFieldListChangeListener mListener;

    public void setOnFieldChangeListener(OnFieldListChangeListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public FieldListAdapter(List<String> fields, Context context, OnStartDragListener dragStartListener){
        mDefaultFields = fields;
        mContext = context;
        mDragStartListener = dragStartListener;
    }
```

The each time I drag the list to re-arrange it, the Fragment is notified like this

```
  @Override
    public void onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        Collections.swap(mDefaultFields, fromPosition, toPosition);
        mListener.onDefaultListChanged(mDefaultFields);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }
```

Then in the Activity of Fragment, you need to keep a copy of the List that you passed to the adapter and then implement that interface and each time the list changes in the Adapter by way of dragging, you simply update the List like this

```
  @Override
    public void onDefaultListChanged(List<String> fields) {
        mFields.setFields(fields);
    }
```

Now you can save this list back to the database and it will retain the new re-arranged position of the list.

Hope it helps.